# Display captured image on Google Glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I trying to display a captured image with Glass Camera and display it in an ImageView.

That's what I do right now:

```
public void startCamera()
{
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 100);       
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
    {
        String photoPath = data.getExtras().getString("picture_file_path");         
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);          
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

However the bitmap is null. When I log the photoPath it gives me a file path like:

/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20131216_195521_665.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Due to processing that occurs on Glass after you take a photo, the file may not be completely written at the time `onActivityResult` is called.

You should use a `FileObserver` as described in the [`CameraManager` javadoc](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/media/CameraManager) to defer your processing until after the file is ready. To do this, have the `FileObserver` observe the **parent directory** of the given path for a `CLOSE_WRITE` event on the file itself. An example of this is provided at the bottom of the page in our [camera developer guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/media-camera/camera).

Comment: Tony thanks for the answer. But Camera javadoc has been expired. Can you please update the link?

Comment: Link updated, and I also added a link to the code sample that we now have up for this logic.

Comment: Tony for updating the link and answers. :)

Comment: Tony, is it normal that it could take 10-15 seconds before this processing is complete, and the file completely available? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Tony Allevato said the problem is that your program does not wait long enough for the file to appear. When I was experimenting with this on XE11 it would often take 5-10 seconds for the file to be readable in the file system. For some reason a FileObserver didn't work for me either, so I implemented a timer, and then I wrote my own activity.

We are hearing that the next release of the GDK will make the snapshot available, so your problem may go away then as you can use that. In the meantime, you might want to consider writing your own activity to take the picture, as I did here:

https://github.com/dazza222/GlassCameraSnapshot